# trying to make call for external style sheet from amazon s3

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, widget

The idea is to make a widget or "chunk" of a website that can be inserted onto someone else's webpage by just adding a script tag to my javascript file located on amazon s3 and a div that I will insert content into.  I also uploaded the css and HTML files to amazon but when I try to make a call to them in the javascript I get errors.  I tried variations of  the code below and got various errors, most recently 403, forbidden.  I made the files public on amazon too.  Please let me know if you have a suggestion/solution!

```
var css_link = $("<link>", { 
  rel: "stylesheet", 
  type: "text/css", 
  href: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/lawkickstas/lawkick.css" 
    });
    css_link.appendTo('head');
var jsonp_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/lawkickstas/lawkick_html.js";

    $.ajax({
                       url: jsonp_url,
                       dataType: 'jsonp',
                       success: function(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
                           console.log(dataWeGotViaJsonp);
                       }
                   });
```

Comment: Why are you loading stylesheets this way?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess from the limited info you have on the error. There is specific setting required on S3 if the access has to be from another domain.

You might want to check this. [Enabling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - Amazon Simple Storage Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)